# Retrofit2. Windows-1251 в UTF-8

Tags: android, xml, кодировка, retrofit

Использую Retrofit2 с Converter-simplexml.
От API получаю XML с кодировкой Windows-1251. Соответственно кириллица отображается вопросительными ромбиками.
Как получить корректное отображение?

Answer (score 1):

Самый верный способ, это заставить сервер отправлять правильную кодировку в заголовке ответа. Предполагаю, что с этим и есть проблема, иначе retrofit бы отрабатывал перекодировку корректно.

Если с сервером никак, то остается только Interceptor, пример кода здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284974/how-to-specify-get-request-encoding-retrofit-okhttp

Comment: Там в примере на C# что ли? Что мне в header писать? Пробовал так:    .header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"). Никакого эффекта

Comment: Там Котлин в примере. На сервере в заголовок надо писать ту кодировку, в которой отправляется тело ответа.

Comment: Но я не могу повлиять на сервер. Значит нет решения?

Comment: Interceptor, его надо правильно написать и подключить. По ссылке есть все примеры кода на Котлине.